# Having problems putting a dgrid into TitlePane

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to put a dojo dgrid into a titlepane as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello dgrid!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dojo/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dojo/dgrid/css/dgrid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dojo/dgrid/css/skins/claro.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <!-- this configuration assumes that the dgrid package is located
         on the filesystem as a sibling to the dojo package -->
    <script src="/dojo/dojo/dojo.js">
        data-dojo-config={async: true, parseOnLoad: true}
        </script>
    <script>
        require(["dijit/TitlePane", "dgrid/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TitlePane,Grid){
    var data = [
        { first: "Bob", last: "Barker", age: 89 },
        { first: "Vanna", last: "White", age: 55 },
        { first: "Pat", last: "Sajak", age: 65 }
    ];

    var grid = new Grid({
        columns: {
            first: "First Name",
            last: "Last Name",
            age: "Age"
        }
    }, "grid");
    grid.renderArray(data);
});
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Pane #1'">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am just not getting the TitlePane to show up. The grid shows up nicely. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Ultimately I am going to be generating a page with a number of grids on it, and looking fora nice way to put the grids into containers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put in "dojo/parser" it worked for me:

```
<script>
        require(["dijit/TitlePane", "dojo/parser","dgrid/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(TitlePane, parser, Grid) {
            parser.parse();
            var data = [{
                first : "Bob",
                last : "Barker",
                age : 89
            }, {
                first : "Vanna",
                last : "White",
                age : 55
            }, {
                first : "Pat",
                last : "Sajak",
                age : 65
            }];

            var grid = new Grid({
                columns : {
                    first : "First Name",
                    last : "Last Name",
                    age : "Age"
                }
            }, "grid");
            grid.renderArray(data);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, still not working for me. Do you have it running somewhere I could see?

Comment: The issue is 'async:true' in your configuration options, if you delete that it should work. However you probably want the asyn loadng so I don't have a perfect solution...some deferred object seems to be blocking loading. http://jsfiddle.net/prsu3k0m/6/

Comment: Thanks, how does one do the data-dojo-config part in fiddler? I didn't see that in your example; so can't fiddle with it...

Comment: In the lefthand side column under 'Fiddler Options' you can change the config in 'Framework <script> attribute'